# Linear differential equation of second order, $b^2 - 4ac < 0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm stuck at finding the solution to the following initial value problem:

$\frac{d^2x}{dt^2} + 2\frac{dx}{dt} +5x=0$

$x(0) = 1, \frac{dx}{dt}(0)=5$

I was trying this:

$r^2+2r+5=0$

$r=\frac{-2 ^+_- \sqrt{-16}}{2}$

I can't take the square root of $-16$ so I'm kinda stuck. Do I maybe have to work with complex numbers?

Thank you

Comment: For sure ! And remember the trigonometric represntation of complex numbers.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici I've found $z_1 = \sqrt{5}(cos(tan^{-1}(2))+isin(tan^{-1}(2)))$ and $z_1 = \sqrt{5}(cos(tan^{-1}(-2))+isin(tan^{-1}(-2)))$. How do I proceed from here?

Comment: Much simpler to stay with $z=-1\pm2i$, no?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a formula that made it fairly simple:

In my case $z=-1\pm2i$

Let's say $u=-1$ and $w=2$ then the solution to my problem is:

$x(t) = (c1*cos(wt) +c2*sin(wt))e^{ut}$

Then I only had to fill in the initial values to find the final solution:

$e^{-t}cos2t+3e^{-t}sin2t$